# How to connect to ML Studio workspace from Python using KeyVault?

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-machine-learning-service

How can I connect to Azure ML Studio workspace using KeyVault (created automatically at the moment of creating a workspace)?

This is how I try to connect to my workspace:

```
from azureml.core import Workspace
from azureml.core.authentication import ServicePrincipalAuthentication

svc_pr = ServicePrincipalAuthentication(
    tenant_id="xxx",
    service_principal_id="yyy",
    service_principal_password="zzz")
ws = Workspace.from_config(auth=svc_pr)
```

But get an error:

> You are currently logged-in to *** tenant. You don't have access to
>   xxx subscription, please check if it is in this tenant. All the
>   subscriptions that you have access to in this tenant are = \n [].

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that the subscription specified in configuration.json file doesn't exist under the tenant specified in ServicePrincipalAuthentication object.

To check if subscription exists under a tenant, you can first use Azure CLI command `az account show` to view the tenant ID, and then command `az account list` to view a list to subscriptions in that tenant.

Comment: May it happen that I should give service principal permissions to access my workspace? (Resource groups -> Access control -> Assign role) Or is it something different?